# How can I check if a Pandas dataframe's index is sorted

Tags: python, pandas

I have a vanilla pandas dataframe with an index. I need to check if the index is sorted. Preferably without sorting it again.

e.g. I can test an index to see if it is unique by index.is_unique() is there a similar way for testing sorted?

Comment: I don't know of a built-in function. If the index is numeric you can do `(np.diff(df.index) >= 0).all()`, since indexes are `np.ndarray`s.

Comment: @katrielalex -- `np.diff` doesn't seem to work with `df.index`; `df.index.values` fixes the problem though...

Comment: @root huh, odd, works for me. Pandas version problem, maybe (I'm on `0.10.1`). Anyway `.values` will work always.

Comment: @katrielalex -- probably (on 0.11.0). Anyway, your comment sounds like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

How about:

`df.index.is_monotonic`

Comment: Use `is_monotonic_increasing` to check for ascending order and `is_monotonic_decreasing` to check for descending order. `is_monotonic` has been deprecated; it's a misnomer as it only checks for increasing monotonicity.

Comment: Does it do a test on the fly, or is it just telling you that at some earlier point you somehow promised pandas that it would be monotonic?

Comment: Is it better to check `is_monotonic` before `sort_index` ? Or  `sort_index` would check it automaticlly .

Comment: @timdiels It is incorrect to say that [`is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_monotonic.html) is deprecated. It is not. Where does it say that it is?

Comment: @Acumenus [It was deprecated at the time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Index.is_monotonic.html) I posted that comment, but seems it no longer is. Still, I wouldn't use it as it only checks whether it is monotonically increasing while a monotonically decreasing function should also be considered monotonic. To be clear, when `is_monotonic_decreasing`, `is_monotic` may be `False`; surprise!

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of completeness, this would be the procedure to check whether the dataframe index is monotonic increasing and also unique, and, if not, make it to be:

```py
if not (df.index.is_monotonic_increasing and df.index.is_unique):
  df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

> NOTE `df.index.is_monotonic_increasing` is returning `True` even if there are repeated indices, so it has to be complemented with `df.index.is_unique`.

#### API References

- [Index.is_monotonic_increasing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_monotonic_increasing.html?highlight=is_monotonic_increasing#pandas-index-is-monotonic-increasing)
- [Index.is_unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.is_unique.html#pandas-index-is-unique)
- [DataFrame.reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_index#pandas-dataframe-reset-index)

Comment: I don't think this is what reset_index does. It will change the index to the default, which for many or all cases is just the row index. I think as others pointed out df.sort_index() is the right tool. It can be done inplace if desired.

Comment: well @Eli, the difference lies on whether the `index.is_unique` or not. If the dataframe index has repeated values, df.sort_index() won't get rid of them. So that, I think my answer above is still valid, and in the case you want to get a dataframe index monotonic increasing and **unique** (the desired index format in most cases, [MultiIndexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) aside), `df.reset_index` is a quick way to get it.

Comment: This may work if you start with a default (integer index) but it will not work with, say, `df = pd.DataFrame(index=[pd.Timestamp(2000,1,1),pd.Timestamp(2000,1,2),pd.Timestamp(2000,1,2),pd.Timestamp(2000,1,3)],data=[0,1,2,3])`. reset_index will keep all four values and replace the timestamps with integer indices [0,1,2,3]. There would be few cases where this is the desired behavior, no?

Comment: Yes, watch out that `reset_index` will modify your indices to be increaing integers! I think having the dataframe index monotonic increasing and unique is good, as it makes the dataframe data (rows) uniquely identifiable by the index itself. In the example you provide @Eli, I would rather move the timestamps to a data column and create a new index with `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`.

Answer (score 2):

If `sort` is all allowed, try

```
all(df.sort_index().index == df.index)
```

If not, try

```
all(a <= b for a, b in zip(df.index, df.index[1:]))
```

The first one is more readable while the second one has smaller time complexity.

### EDIT

Add another method I've just found. Similar with the second one but the comparison is vetorized

```
all(df.index[:-1] <= df.index[1:])
```

Comment: Strongly recommend using `is_monotonic`

Answer (score 1):

For non-indices:

```
df.equals(df.sort())
```

Comment: Do note, `is_monotonic_increasing` and `is_monotonic_decreasing` work for non-indexes also.